# How to start a service after installing .apk file in Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I need to start a service after installing the application and without opening it. I have searched a lot, but didn't find anything useful. I now that the way to do that is to make a broadcast receiver which will start the service upon receiving a specified action, and i should register it in the manifest file. I tried on boot complete action, and it worked well. But how can i can i handle after install. Please any help will be appreciated.

Comment: see [this question ][1]  it can be helpful


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839277/android-notification-after-app-is-installed-on-device-how-to