# How do I tell the system to do setup() when my android app is installed?

Tags: android

I would like to make an album and add some music files when my android app is first installed on a device.  Is there a way is can do something like below?

```
public void onInstall(){
    setup();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything after the app is installed, only after it is run.

Just store a flag in your SharedPreferences to see whether or not it has done its first-time install process already and then perform it, or, if you're installing music files, check for their existence and install them if they're not there yet.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to know when your app is installed... however, you can detect when it's first launched. It has been discussed a lot of times here. You just need to persist it using a shared preference.

Answer (score 0):

here comes the answer ;-)

[Get referrer after installing app from Android Market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093150/get-referrer-after-installing-app-from-android-market)