# Launch application on install and also without launcher icon

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am building a application which has no launcher icon. i nead to launch the application on first time it get installed from play store.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are targeting Android 3.0 and before, you can use the broadcast sent by the installer once your app has been installed, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4093150/1069068).

However, starting Android 3.0, you cannot receive broadcasts until the user has opened an Activity in your app at least once. Due to this, you cannot auto launch on Android 3.1 and later.

Comment: My android api version is 2.3

Comment: @user2071490 API version doesn't matter. What matters is the version of Android installing the app.

Comment: i made a free app, now i am making a paid app for that free app both have different features like mkplayer.

Comment: and paid app has no launcher icon. if someone install paid app first then application must give alert to download free app to run.

Comment: @user2071490 You should really be using in app billing for that kind of unlocker. The best you can do is to check to see from the free app if the paid app has been installed everytime it starts. That way, your app can check if the user has installed the paid app and unlock accordingly.

Comment: That i had done it if paid app is installed features get enable in free app, but problem occurred when the paid app is installed first.