# Intercept Android App's Downloading and Installation Process

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play, android-package-managers

Is there  any notification sent after an app is downloaded and before it is installed? I want to create a service in android that activates on receiving such notification. That is, my service must perform some check **before** it is **installed** , but **after** it is **downloaded**.
The below link gives the soln for notification **after installation**.
[Get referrer after installing app from Android Market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093150/get-referrer-after-installing-app-from-android-market)

Comment: No i dint find any soln to above problem.... i guess package manager and package installer for android needs to be modified to hook up between the downloading and installation

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do something before an app is installed but before it is downloaded.

The first problem is (obviously) that your package is not installed yet. The OS cannot launch a Service from a package that has not been installed because the OS has no idea that Service exists.

If you provide more information on why you want to interrupt this process, we may be able to provide more information on how to accomplish that.

Comment: The service is an independent service that is a part of my system and not the package to be installed.I just want to hook up the download-install process to scan the downloaded application.(before it installs).