# Android referrer parameters are not getting captured

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, install-referrer

I have an custom `INSTALL_REFERRER`, a custom class that extends the `BroadcastReceiver` class, and a link that goes to my app

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myapp.android&referrer=ai%3Dai_value%26gclid%3Dgclid_test

This link has the obvious `referrer` params and values: `ai=ai_value&gclid=gclid_test`.

When I run my app in my development `adb shell`, I am able to capture both of these parameters and values on the `BroadcastReceiver` and send it back to my server. Here's the `adb` command that I'm running:

```
am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.myapp.android/.CustomInstallReceiver --es "referrer" "ai%3Dai_value%26gclid%3Dgclid_test"
```

However, when it's live in the app store, I'm only able to capture the first param and value. Any idea what's going on or what I can check?

Answer (score 5):

Accoring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093150/get-referrer-after-installing-app-from-android-market) post, **you cannot use custom query-string parameters** (only *referrer* is accepted).

The good thing is that **you can easly trick the problem**: just "inject" the second key/value pair in the first parameter using a custom separator which is standard-complaint (so don't use the *&*) and treat it accordingly server side by splitting your values using the custom separator. In this way, the whole information will be transported using the working key "*referrer*".