# How i can send invitation to my contact to install my application

Tags: android

I am creating application like hotel management. i work is good but i want one main facility in my application. I am implementing a one button when am click on this it will fetch my contact list and when i am selecting a contact from contact list. I want to send message using Internet. In this message i want to Refer my contact to install my application. But how i can implement in my application i really don't know. So please if anyone have code like this or any reference then please share with me. Thank You in advance.

Comment: Please add more details like the language you are using,  the software architecture and e.g. some code examples.

Comment: i dont have any code like to post on it.

Comment: You don't have any code... and ask for code here? This post will have a very short life, here.

Comment: Sorry sir but new in android. N i am just think about it to add on my application but i really don't know that's why i will post this question.

Answer (score 0):

I recently developed this type of application.

**Try this.**

Part 1: to send / share the message

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
// carefully observe the package name with `referrer` query param.
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your message goes here. Append this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.shreemeera.apps.petals&referrer=pramod.waghmare");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"Share your app name"));
```

Part 2: Know who refer to install your application
 Refer : [Get referrer after installing app from Android Market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093150/get-referrer-after-installing-app-from-android-market)

Comment: Sorry sir i am already try this but i don't have 50 reputation. I am new in android and stackoverflow also. but why people are decrement the vote i really don't know. Sorry Sir n thank you for such good solution

Comment: Try to ask question properly. It may affect to your reputation like your language, code, hint, relevant question and much more.

Comment: No not now first i will purchasing it to google play store after that i will implement user solution.

Comment: i will tried u r solution but ACTION_SEND Intent will shows all the sharing app through the intent . But i just want MyContact app in my Intent to share the application

Comment: Share my application through my contact list only

Comment: you means contact ? or send simple message from contact list?

Comment: Yes sir. I want to send simple free app sharing message like hike.through my contact