Android app link doesn't navigate to Play Store when app is not installed but works correctly when the app is installed
Most questions about app links not working are about app links navigating to Play Store even when the app is installed (instead of launching the app).
I have the opposite problem. When the app is installed, the app link works as expected. But when the app is not installed, the link just opens in the browser. I doublechecked https://domain/.well-known/assetlinks.json and ran all the possible validation tools. I'm also relatively certain it used to work until a few weeks ago.
Any ideas what am I missing?

Looks like there's some readability issues, you must have to update this for best demonstrate your perceptive

It's obvious if your app is installed with your defined URI, your system will look for it and show the app that supports opening that URL.
But if you want to make it in such a way that if your app is not installed your URL will redirect to Play Store you have to write your backend using Firebase Deep linking
Solution Cases With DeepLinking:
URL clicked with app not installed => Firebase deep linking URL will redirect your user to the Play Store or App Store based on the device type.
URL Clicked with the app installed =>  Your URL will be redirected to your app
You can achieve this using the Firebase Dynamic linking but it'll going to deprecate by the end of 25 August 2025
I'd prefer to go with alternative plans sunch as https://dynalinks.app/

Thanks. Do you mean to say that App Links don't automatically navigate to play store? All the documentation says that it does.

I guess it's indeed doesn't work the way I expected and what I remember to see working was Firebase Deep Links. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41643834/android-deep-linking-if-user-does-not-have-the-app-installed

yes just implementing the deep link in the app without any server will not work at all. There must be a server to decide what to do with the link, to redirect to Playstore/Appstore/Website itself, etc.
