# App Store link parameters / InstallReferrerReceiver equivalent on iOS

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm aware that on Android you have the ability to add the parameter `referrer` to a Play Store URL the parameter will be passed to the app on app launch...

e.g.

http://market.android.com/details?id=your.application.package.name&referrer=my_referrer_finally_works_fine

Is there a similar parameter on iOS? I'm looking to link my users to the app store and launch them into a specific screen once they launch.

**Links for InstallReferrerReceiver**

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tagmanager/InstallReferrerReceiver

[Get referrer after installing app from Android Market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093150/get-referrer-after-installing-app-from-android-market)

Comment: hi @Magoo I cannot open your android market link. Can you fix it?

Comment: It's just an example.....

Comment: sorry, I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

I went with a mixture of Firebase and universal links in the end

https://firebase.google.com/

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html