# InstallReferrerReceiver not working in live app

Tags: android, android-studio, install-referrer

I am developing an app in android studio and tracking referrer using referral link but my app not working in live condition

My app work fine when I send referrer using below command

```
adb shell
am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.example.app/.InstallReferrerReceiver --es "referrer" "123456"
```

but when I install my app using play store link `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?com.example.app&referrer=123456` then my app is not receiveing referrer

I already added receiver in my manifest file under application tag.

```
<receiver
    android:name=".InstallReferrerReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

My InstallReferrerReciver

```
public class InstallReferrerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String referrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        if (referrer != null) {
            preferences.edit().putString("referral_code", referrer).apply();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

INSTALL_REFERRER is no longer broadcast to the receiver [since March 2020](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/11/still-using-installbroadcast-switch-to.html). Now if you want to use referral program in android app then you need to use [Google Play Install Referrer API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer)