# Is it possible to get infomation such as how long your application has been installed and user demographic

Tags: android, analytics

I am implementing Google analytic into my android app and I have got all the page views, click event analytic's I want.

I am now wanting to know how long the user has had my app installed for and if possible their demographic such as age and sex (note, my application dosnt ask the user for this information so I assume its not possible).

Also is there any other useful information I can collect which is generic between all apps and how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, if you are not asking for this information then it is difficult to obtain.

Here's a post that talks about recognizing when the app is installed for the first time. So when this happens, you could make a call to GA or save the time/date to a remote database.

[Is there on install event in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227604/is-there-on-install-event-in-android)