# Execute Android code after installation

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there on install event in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227604/is-there-on-install-event-in-android)

I want to execute a piece of code only once after installation complete in an Android app. This code should never be executed in the application there after.

Can anyone tell me how to do this.

Reagrds,

Shankar

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I tried below code to make this work change it to suit your needs

```
SharedPreferences wmbPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean isFirstRun = wmbPreference.getBoolean("FIRSTRUN", true);
if (isFirstRun)
{
    // Code to run once
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = wmbPreference.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("FIRSTRUN", false);
    //editor.commit();
    editor.apply(); 
}
```

Comment: Use editor.apply(); instead.

Comment: If the app is updated i.e a new version is installed on top of existing version - then what is the status of isFirstRun?

Comment: Then it will return false

Comment: Where will I write your above code so that I could run some code after successful installation? I meant, Do I need to create a activity and write somewhere that this will run first on successful installation?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of an Shared Prefrence to maintain the number the times the app has been launched. So now if the app has been launched for the first time you can execute your code, if not you can just skip it.Here is a perfect demo for it.

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/63.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question: [Is there on install event in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227604/is-there-on-install-event-in-android)

There it is explained how to receive an event when the application is first installed/executed. You can listen to it and then execute your code.

Comment: Would be great IF the app being installed could hear it. So the only option is to do what you have to do on the first start.