# How to Handle Events when Install Apk file

Tags: android, event-handling, android-install-apk

I need handle event when I click on the APK file like this.
[image]

I want to do something when this dialog show out, don't need handle events of buttons "Cancel" or "Install". How can I do that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227604/is-there-on-install-event-in-android

Answer (score 0):

When the app Installation complete.
android os will send a broadcast
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
you can use intent.getDataString()
get the packageName