# is there any hooks when android install app

Tags: android

I want to develop a app for by kids that I can control the kids android device app install, I need to capture the android install app event and send the request to another device to decide whether the install request is allowed, it allowed, process the install procedure, if not, stop the app install process. is there any install event hooks in andriod?

Comment: Are you asking something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227604/is-there-on-install-event-in-android

Comment: "if not stop the app install process" -- that is not an option, except perhaps with device owner APIs, used by MDM systems. "I want to develop a app for by kids that I can control the kids android device app install" -- have you discussed your plans with your attorney?